# How to Tint Buttons on Calender Entry View (EKEventEditViewController)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, eventkit

I am trying the following to **change the tint of the done/cancel buttons** on a default EventKitUI - "Add Event" Calendar Entry Sheet.

[image: Calendar Entry Sheet]

```
EKEventEditViewController *eventController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc]init];    
eventController.editViewDelegate = self;

[[[eventController navigationItem]cancelButton]setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

But the buttons still keep the color inherited from the previous navigationbar as displayed in the image above (curiously the sheet didn't take over the navigation bar tint from the previous navigation bar, which was also grey).

How to access and change the button tint on this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change the tint of the Navigationbar like this.

```
eventController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greyColor];
```